# API calls to server stopped executing when running on Android

Tags: android, flutter, api

I writing code for an application in Flutter and testing it simultaneously on android and Windows. My backend code is in node js. I was trying to add permissions to my AndroidManifest.xml for camera when all of a sudden, API calls to backend using android stopped executing i.e nothing was being sent to backend. I reversed the changes in the AndroidManifest.xml but am unable to reverse this issue

The code in my AndroidManifest.xml is below
[image]

The below code is the call to api which i am trying to make
[image]

Comment: Did you add the Internet permission on your manifest (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting)?

Comment: yes, it isnt making any difference.

Comment: There are no errors? Only calls never responding?

Comment: Okay I tried again and the terminal shows me this "D/InputTransport(16759): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=142

Comment: But it doesnt explicitly give an error